# PHP Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float

Tags: php, string, number-formatting

Can you please someone help me with this code I got

> PHP Warning:  number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in line 39

I am copied the whole class I hope that will help you better to find the problem.

```
   class stats_site extends stats {
      function __construct() {
        global $CONF, $DB, $FORM, $LNG, $TMPL;

    $TMPL['header'] = $LNG['stats_header'];

    $TMPL['username'] = $DB->escape($FORM['u'], 1);

    $stats = $DB->fetch("SELECT * FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_stats WHERE username = '{$TMPL['username']}'", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    unset($stats['username']);

    $sites = array($DB->fetch("SELECT * FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_sites WHERE username = '{$TMPL['username']}'", __FILE__, __LINE__));
    if ($stats) {
      $TMPL = array_merge($TMPL, $stats, $sites);

      $TMPL['unq_pv_max_daily'] = $TMPL['unq_pv_0_daily'] > $TMPL['unq_pv_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['unq_pv_0_daily'] : $TMPL['unq_pv_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['tot_pv_max_daily'] = $TMPL['tot_pv_0_daily'] > $TMPL['tot_pv_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['tot_pv_0_daily'] : $TMPL['tot_pv_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['unq_in_max_daily'] = $TMPL['unq_in_0_daily'] > $TMPL['unq_in_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['unq_in_0_daily'] : $TMPL['unq_in_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['tot_in_max_daily'] = $TMPL['tot_in_0_daily'] > $TMPL['tot_in_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['tot_in_0_daily'] : $TMPL['tot_in_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['unq_out_max_daily'] = $TMPL['unq_out_0_daily'] > $TMPL['unq_out_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['unq_out_0_daily'] : $TMPL['unq_out_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['tot_out_max_daily'] = $TMPL['tot_out_0_daily'] > $TMPL['tot_out_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['tot_out_0_daily'] : $TMPL['tot_out_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['unq_pv_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['unq_pv_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['unq_pv_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['unq_pv_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['unq_pv_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['tot_pv_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['tot_pv_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['tot_pv_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['tot_pv_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['tot_pv_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['unq_in_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['unq_in_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['unq_in_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['unq_in_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['unq_in_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['tot_in_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['tot_in_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['tot_in_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['tot_in_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['tot_in_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['unq_out_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['unq_out_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['unq_out_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['unq_out_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['unq_out_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['tot_out_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['tot_out_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['tot_out_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['tot_out_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['tot_out_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['unq_pv_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['unq_pv_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['unq_pv_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['unq_pv_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['unq_pv_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['tot_pv_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['tot_pv_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['tot_pv_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['tot_pv_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['tot_pv_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['unq_in_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['unq_in_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['unq_in_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['unq_in_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['unq_in_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['tot_in_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['tot_in_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['tot_in_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['tot_in_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['tot_in_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['unq_out_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['unq_out_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['unq_out_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['unq_out_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['unq_out_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['tot_out_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['tot_out_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['tot_out_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['tot_out_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['tot_out_max_monthly'];

      $this->averages();

      $TMPL['average_rating'] = $TMPL['num_ratings'] > 0 ? round($TMPL['total_rating'] / $TMPL['num_ratings'], 0) : 0;

      $stats = array_map('number_format', $stats);
      $TMPL = array_merge($TMPL, $stats);

      $this->locale();

      $TMPL['header'] .= " - {$TMPL['title']}";
      $TMPL['category_url'] = urlencode($TMPL['category']);

      $query = "SELECT id, date, review FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_reviews WHERE username = '{$TMPL['username']}' AND active = 1";
      if (isset($FORM['all_reviews']) && $FORM['all_reviews']) {
        $result = $DB->query("{$query} ORDER BY date DESC", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      }
      else {
        $result = $DB->select_limit("{$query} ORDER BY RAND()", 2, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
      }
      $TMPL['reviews'] = '';
      while (list($TMPL['id'], $TMPL['date'], $TMPL['review']) = $DB->fetch_array($result)) {
        $TMPL['reviews'] .= $this->do_skin('stats_review');
      }

      $TMPL['content'] = $this->do_skin('stats');
    }
    else {
      $this->error($LNG['g_invalid_u']);
    }
  }
}
```

And line 39 is this line here:

```
$stats = array_map('number_format', $stats);
```

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I've  put here THE FULL CODE so you can better fix the problem with it.
I tried everything you advice here but it doesn't help :(

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

if (!defined('ATSPHP')) {
  die("This file cannot be accessed directly.");
}

class stats extends base {
  function __construct() {
    global $FORM;

    if (isset($FORM['u'])) { $stats = new stats_site; }
    else { $stats = new stats_overall; }
  }

  function averages() {
    global $TMPL;

    $ranking_periods = array('daily', 'weekly', 'monthly');
    $ranking_methods = array('unq_pv', 'tot_pv', 'unq_in', 'tot_in', 'unq_out', 'tot_out');
    foreach ($ranking_periods as $ranking_period) {
      foreach ($ranking_methods as $ranking_method) {
        $TMPL["{$ranking_method}_avg_{$ranking_period}"] = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
          $TMPL["{$ranking_method}_avg_{$ranking_period}"] = $TMPL["{$ranking_method}_avg_{$ranking_period}"] + $TMPL["{$ranking_method}_{$i}_{$ranking_period}"];
        }
        $TMPL["{$ranking_method}_avg_{$ranking_period}"] = number_format($TMPL["{$ranking_method}_avg_{$ranking_period}"] / 10, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  function locale() {
    global $CONF, $LNG, $TMPL;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, $CONF['default_language']);
    for ($i = 2; $i < 10; $i++) {
      $TMPL["{$i}_daily"] = strftime('%B %d', time()-3600*24*$i + (3600*$CONF['time_offset']));
    }
    for ($i = 2; $i < 10; $i++) {
      $TMPL["{$i}_weekly"] = "{$LNG['stats_week']} ".date('W', time()-3600*24*7*$i + (3600*$CONF['time_offset']));
    }
    for ($i = 2; $i < 10; $i++) {
      $TMPL["{$i}_monthly"] = strftime('%B %y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-$i, 1));
    }
  }
}

class stats_site extends stats {
  function __construct() {
    global $CONF, $DB, $FORM, $LNG, $TMPL;

    $TMPL['header'] = $LNG['stats_header'];

    $TMPL['username'] = $DB->escape($FORM['u'], 1);

    $stats = $DB->fetch("SELECT * FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_stats WHERE username = '{$TMPL['username']}'", __FILE__, __LINE__);
    unset($stats['username']);

    $sites = array($DB->fetch("SELECT * FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_sites WHERE username = '{$TMPL['username']}'", __FILE__, __LINE__));
    if ($stats) {
      $TMPL = array_merge($TMPL, $stats, $sites);

      $TMPL['unq_pv_max_daily'] = $TMPL['unq_pv_0_daily'] > $TMPL['unq_pv_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['unq_pv_0_daily'] : $TMPL['unq_pv_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['tot_pv_max_daily'] = $TMPL['tot_pv_0_daily'] > $TMPL['tot_pv_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['tot_pv_0_daily'] : $TMPL['tot_pv_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['unq_in_max_daily'] = $TMPL['unq_in_0_daily'] > $TMPL['unq_in_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['unq_in_0_daily'] : $TMPL['unq_in_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['tot_in_max_daily'] = $TMPL['tot_in_0_daily'] > $TMPL['tot_in_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['tot_in_0_daily'] : $TMPL['tot_in_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['unq_out_max_daily'] = $TMPL['unq_out_0_daily'] > $TMPL['unq_out_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['unq_out_0_daily'] : $TMPL['unq_out_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['tot_out_max_daily'] = $TMPL['tot_out_0_daily'] > $TMPL['tot_out_max_daily'] ? $TMPL['tot_out_0_daily'] : $TMPL['tot_out_max_daily'];
      $TMPL['unq_pv_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['unq_pv_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['unq_pv_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['unq_pv_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['unq_pv_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['tot_pv_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['tot_pv_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['tot_pv_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['tot_pv_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['tot_pv_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['unq_in_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['unq_in_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['unq_in_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['unq_in_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['unq_in_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['tot_in_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['tot_in_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['tot_in_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['tot_in_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['tot_in_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['unq_out_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['unq_out_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['unq_out_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['unq_out_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['unq_out_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['tot_out_max_weekly'] = $TMPL['tot_out_0_weekly'] > $TMPL['tot_out_max_weekly'] ? $TMPL['tot_out_0_weekly'] : $TMPL['tot_out_max_weekly'];
      $TMPL['unq_pv_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['unq_pv_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['unq_pv_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['unq_pv_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['unq_pv_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['tot_pv_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['tot_pv_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['tot_pv_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['tot_pv_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['tot_pv_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['unq_in_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['unq_in_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['unq_in_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['unq_in_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['unq_in_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['tot_in_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['tot_in_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['tot_in_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['tot_in_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['tot_in_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['unq_out_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['unq_out_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['unq_out_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['unq_out_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['unq_out_max_monthly'];
      $TMPL['tot_out_max_monthly'] = $TMPL['tot_out_0_monthly'] > $TMPL['tot_out_max_monthly'] ? $TMPL['tot_out_0_monthly'] : $TMPL['tot_out_max_monthly'];

      $this->averages();

      $TMPL['average_rating'] = $TMPL['num_ratings'] > 0 ? round($TMPL['total_rating'] / $TMPL['num_ratings'], 0) : 0;
      function formatter($stats) { return number_format(floatval($stats)); }
      $stats = array_map('number_format', $stats);
      //$stats = array_map(function($v){return is_numeric($v) ? number_format($v) : $v;}, $stats);
      $TMPL = array_merge($TMPL, $stats);

      $this->locale();

      $TMPL['header'] .= " - {$TMPL['title']}";
      $TMPL['category_url'] = urlencode($TMPL['category']);

      $query = "SELECT id, date, review FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_reviews WHERE username = '{$TMPL['username']}' AND active = 1";
      if (isset($FORM['all_reviews']) && $FORM['all_reviews']) {
        $result = $DB->query("{$query} ORDER BY date DESC", __FILE__, __LINE__);
      }
      else {
        $result = $DB->select_limit("{$query} ORDER BY RAND()", 2, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__);
      }
      $TMPL['reviews'] = '';
      while (list($TMPL['id'], $TMPL['date'], $TMPL['review']) = $DB->fetch_array($result)) {
        $TMPL['reviews'] .= $this->do_skin('stats_review');
      }

      $TMPL['content'] = $this->do_skin('stats');
    }
    else {
      $this->error($LNG['g_invalid_u']);
    }
  }
}

class stats_overall extends stats {
  function __construct() {
    global $CONF, $DB, $FORM, $LNG, $TMPL;

    $TMPL['header'] = $LNG['stats_overall'];

    $stats = $DB->fetch("SELECT SUM(unq_pv_overall), SUM(tot_pv_overall), SUM(unq_in_overall), SUM(tot_in_overall), SUM(unq_out_overall), SUM(tot_out_overall),
                         SUM(unq_pv_0_daily), SUM(unq_pv_1_daily), SUM(unq_pv_2_daily), SUM(unq_pv_3_daily), SUM(unq_pv_4_daily), SUM(unq_pv_5_daily), SUM(unq_pv_6_daily), SUM(unq_pv_7_daily), SUM(unq_pv_8_daily), SUM(unq_pv_9_daily), SUM(tot_pv_0_daily), SUM(tot_pv_1_daily), SUM(tot_pv_2_daily), SUM(tot_pv_3_daily), SUM(tot_pv_4_daily), SUM(tot_pv_5_daily), SUM(tot_pv_6_daily), SUM(tot_pv_7_daily), SUM(tot_pv_8_daily), SUM(tot_pv_9_daily),
                         SUM(unq_in_0_daily), SUM(unq_in_1_daily), SUM(unq_in_2_daily), SUM(unq_in_3_daily), SUM(unq_in_4_daily), SUM(unq_in_5_daily), SUM(unq_in_6_daily), SUM(unq_in_7_daily), SUM(unq_in_8_daily), SUM(unq_in_9_daily), SUM(tot_in_0_daily), SUM(tot_in_1_daily), SUM(tot_in_2_daily), SUM(tot_in_3_daily), SUM(tot_in_4_daily), SUM(tot_in_5_daily), SUM(tot_in_6_daily), SUM(tot_in_7_daily), SUM(tot_in_8_daily), SUM(tot_in_9_daily),
                         SUM(unq_out_0_daily), SUM(unq_out_1_daily), SUM(unq_out_2_daily), SUM(unq_out_3_daily), SUM(unq_out_4_daily), SUM(unq_out_5_daily), SUM(unq_out_6_daily), SUM(unq_out_7_daily), SUM(unq_out_8_daily), SUM(unq_out_9_daily), SUM(tot_out_0_daily), SUM(tot_out_1_daily), SUM(tot_out_2_daily), SUM(tot_out_3_daily), SUM(tot_out_4_daily), SUM(tot_out_5_daily), SUM(tot_out_6_daily), SUM(tot_out_7_daily), SUM(tot_out_8_daily), SUM(tot_out_9_daily),
                         SUM(unq_pv_0_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_1_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_2_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_3_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_4_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_5_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_6_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_7_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_8_weekly), SUM(unq_pv_9_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_0_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_1_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_2_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_3_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_4_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_5_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_6_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_7_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_8_weekly), SUM(tot_pv_9_weekly),
                         SUM(unq_in_0_weekly), SUM(unq_in_1_weekly), SUM(unq_in_2_weekly), SUM(unq_in_3_weekly), SUM(unq_in_4_weekly), SUM(unq_in_5_weekly), SUM(unq_in_6_weekly), SUM(unq_in_7_weekly), SUM(unq_in_8_weekly), SUM(unq_in_9_weekly), SUM(tot_in_0_weekly), SUM(tot_in_1_weekly), SUM(tot_in_2_weekly), SUM(tot_in_3_weekly), SUM(tot_in_4_weekly), SUM(tot_in_5_weekly), SUM(tot_in_6_weekly), SUM(tot_in_7_weekly), SUM(tot_in_8_weekly), SUM(tot_in_9_weekly),
                         SUM(unq_out_0_weekly), SUM(unq_out_1_weekly), SUM(unq_out_2_weekly), SUM(unq_out_3_weekly), SUM(unq_out_4_weekly), SUM(unq_out_5_weekly), SUM(unq_out_6_weekly), SUM(unq_out_7_weekly), SUM(unq_out_8_weekly), SUM(unq_out_9_weekly), SUM(tot_out_0_weekly), SUM(tot_out_1_weekly), SUM(tot_out_2_weekly), SUM(tot_out_3_weekly), SUM(tot_out_4_weekly), SUM(tot_out_5_weekly), SUM(tot_out_6_weekly), SUM(tot_out_7_weekly), SUM(tot_out_8_weekly), SUM(tot_out_9_weekly),
                         SUM(unq_pv_0_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_1_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_2_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_3_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_4_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_5_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_6_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_7_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_8_monthly), SUM(unq_pv_9_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_0_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_1_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_2_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_3_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_4_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_5_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_6_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_7_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_8_monthly), SUM(tot_pv_9_monthly),
                         SUM(unq_in_0_monthly), SUM(unq_in_1_monthly), SUM(unq_in_2_monthly), SUM(unq_in_3_monthly), SUM(unq_in_4_monthly), SUM(unq_in_5_monthly), SUM(unq_in_6_monthly), SUM(unq_in_7_monthly), SUM(unq_in_8_monthly), SUM(unq_in_9_monthly),  SUM(tot_in_0_monthly), SUM(tot_in_1_monthly), SUM(tot_in_2_monthly), SUM(tot_in_3_monthly), SUM(tot_in_4_monthly), SUM(tot_in_5_monthly), SUM(tot_in_6_monthly), SUM(tot_in_7_monthly), SUM(tot_in_8_monthly), SUM(tot_in_9_monthly),
                         SUM(unq_out_0_monthly), SUM(unq_out_1_monthly), SUM(unq_out_2_monthly), SUM(unq_out_3_monthly), SUM(unq_out_4_monthly), SUM(unq_out_5_monthly), SUM(unq_out_6_monthly), SUM(unq_out_7_monthly), SUM(unq_out_8_monthly), SUM(unq_out_9_monthly), SUM(tot_out_0_monthly), SUM(tot_out_1_monthly), SUM(tot_out_2_monthly), SUM(tot_out_3_monthly), SUM(tot_out_4_monthly), SUM(tot_out_5_monthly), SUM(tot_out_6_monthly), SUM(tot_out_7_monthly), SUM(tot_out_8_monthly), SUM(tot_out_9_monthly)
                         FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_stats", __FILE__, __LINE__);

    // Get rid of SUM() in array keys
    foreach ($stats as $key => $value) {
      $new_key = str_replace(array('SUM(', ')'), '', $key);
      $stats[$new_key] = $value;
      unset($stats[$key]);
    }

    $TMPL = array_merge($TMPL, $stats);

    $this->averages();

    $stats = array_map('number_format', $stats);
    $TMPL = array_merge($TMPL, $stats);

    $this->locale();

    $TMPL['content'] = $this->do_skin('stats_overall');
  }
}
?>
```

Error happen at line 85:

```
$stats = array_map('number_format', $stats);
```

---

Latest Error after using Miken32's Answer:

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: title in sources/stats.php on line 91 
>   PHP Notice: Undefined index: category in sources/stats.php on line 92 
>   PHP Notice: Undefined index: title in sources/misc/skin.php(84) : runtime-created function on line 1  
>   PHP Notice: Undefined index: url in sources/misc/ etc.

Comment: What is in `$stats`? At least one element of that array is not numeric.

Comment: @miken32 I put now the full PHP code, can you please help me here now ? None of variants you provided still doesn't helped! Many thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer two days ago.

Comment: @miken32 I tried but it doesn't solved my problem, you have the full page code now I edited my post above.

Comment: @Farer if you tried Miken32's answer; the error would be *different* from the error you stated at line 85; what is the *different* error that using Miken32's code gives you? Or otherwise clarify *HOW* it doesn't work

Comment: No; if you used either of the answers provided, you would not be getting that error message.

Comment: @miken32 Here is copy/paste my error I just got by replacing with the code you provide: [02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in sources/stats.php on line 91
[02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: category in sources/stats.php on line 92
[02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in sources/misc/skin.php(84) : runtime-created function on line 1
[02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in sources/misc/
etc.

Comment: @Martin Send me please where is the comment you doesn't agreed with it and I will remove it ASAP, I can't found it. Thank you.

Comment: @Farer I have updated your question. Regardless of these *Notices*, do you get the correct **output** from the PHPscript, now?

Comment: @Martin yes yes Martin, thanks for the update I think I can solve the problem with those notices of Undefined indexed with maybe putting PHP code like ?> $var = isset($var) ? $var : ''; <? but I am affraid with notice message part like "runtime-created function on line 1" - I see that first time ... ?? What to do with that? Thanks!

Comment: Personally; I don't care about notices much; they're **not** warnings; they're *just* notices. Good luck.

Comment: @Martin Okay I can partially agree, but (maybe I am perfectionist?) I like to work correctly when I work on something also if you got too much those notices your server is slower and slower also if you log this notices, you have more and more abused space on server etc. So I like to have all this SOLVED. That means without any errors or notices.

Comment: @Martin Also if something YOU do, that of corse doesn't mean that I HAVE to do it too, like you, lol... :))

Comment: If you *were* a perfectionist, you would burn your code and rewrite it from scratch `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_map()` applies a function to each element of the array. In this case you're passing it the name of a function ("number_format") that expects a number but it's getting a string. Instead, you can pass it your own function that can check it:

```
$stats = array_map(function($v){return is_numeric($v) ? number_format($v) : $v;}, $stats);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't helped me, you can see in full code that I commented out that line when I tried it and recognize it isn't fixed my problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Farer if you tried Miken32's answer; the error would be *different* from the error you stated at line 85; what is the *different* error that using Miken32's code gives you? Or otherwise clarify HOW it doesn't work

Comment: @Martin Yes, now error is diferent, here I got now this errors:

Comment: @Farer well..... then instead of saying "it doesn't work" to Miken32, **edit** your question and add at the bottom the *new* error message that appears with the answer given above. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin Undefined index: title on line 91 Undefined index: category on line 92 Undefined index: title runtime-created function on line 1 Undefined index: url runtime-created function on line 1 PHP Notice: Undefined index: banner_ url runtime-created function on line 1 Undefined index: title untime-created function on line 1 // etc...

Comment: @Martin Okay I will remove that comment I don't know, sorry about my missunderstanding English, I am still learning :)) Thanks!

Comment: @miken32 New notices now happen after I added your code: [02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in sources/stats.php on line 91
[02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: category in sources/stats.php on line 92
[02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in sources/misc/skin.php(84) : runtime-created function on line 1
[02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in sources/misc/skin.php(84) : runtime-created function on line 1
[02-Oct-2018 22:45:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  U runtime-created function on line 1

Answer (score 0):

By default numeric types from MySQL are returned as string values in php.  The easiest thing to do would be create a custom function and pass that in:

```
function formatter($value) { return number_format(floatval($value)); }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes I know there wasn't something good and because of that I'm getting an error, anyway I am not asking WHAT but HOW ?

Comment: See my response above.  Basically you're calling the number_format() method directly, but you need something in the middle.  So if you copy/paste the formatter function I wrote into your code, you could change that line to:
`$stats = array_map('formatter', $stats);`
and it will work.  Basically the data has to be converted into a float first. That's all.

Comment: Re-reading your code, it is also problematic that $stats will be an array of arrays, you can *not* throw an array into number_format, and floatval will give you weird results.  You should definitely do some more data massaging in the formatter function I wrote above.

Comment: I will try with that code you send me "$stats = array_map('formatter', $stats);" if not, then I will copy the whole code from a page and paste it here, thank you!